# Hibernate critieria query with dynamic or statement

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, criteria

I am writing a query with Hibernate Criteria. I am trying to find entities associated with a specific location.   Each location can consist of country, province, city, latitude and longitude.  Each location will be stored as a different object in the database depending on how many of the fields are used.  For example, country the could be a country object where all the fields but country are null, and a province object, where the country and province fields are filled but everything else is null.

When a user logs in the application determines their location. The amount of location objects associated with a user will therefore be dynamic, depending on their location.  For example, there may not be the appropriate location object for the city in the database.

I have created a criteria for the locations associated with the user.  This is working fine.... (sample code below)

```
Criteria locationCriteria = session.createCriteria(Location.class);
        locationCriteria.add(Restrictions.and(
                Restrictions.or(
                        Restrictions.isNull("province"),
                        Restrictions.eq("province", province)
                ),
                Restrictions.or(
                        Restrictions.isNull("country"),
                        Restrictions.eq("country", country)
                )
        ));
```

There is also a database table containing entities that have a manyToMany relationship with locations. Ultimately, I am trying to find all the entities associated with all the locations associated with the logged in user.  The problem now is that I need to use a dynamically sized location criteria.list() as a restriction to get the entities that are associated with each location.  Since the list is dynamic, I cannot use Restrictions.or() for the locations.

I am considering iterating over each value from locationCriteria.list() and recreating the query for each entity, but I'm worried about the performance as the database grows in size.  I have implemented it for now, however, and it is working (seen below).

```
for (int i = 0; i < locationCriteria.list().size(); i++) {

            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Entity.class);

            criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
            criteria.createAlias("locations", "locations");
            Location l = (Location) locationCriteria.list().get(i);

            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("locations.id", l.getId()));
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(availability, true));
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("active", true));
            try {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.or(
                        Restrictions.isNull("startDate"),
                        Restrictions.le("startDate", dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(date)))
                ));
            } catch (ParseException p) {
                p.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.or(
                        Restrictions.isNull("endDate"),
                        Restrictions.ge("endDate", dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(date)))
                ));
            } catch (ParseException p) {
                p.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (Object ob : criteria.list()) {
                Entity entity = (Entity) ob;
                EntityModel pm = new EntityModel(entity);
                entityModels.add(pm);
            }
        }
```

What should I do?  I don't want to iterate over the entire database for every location, but I can't find a way to handle a dynamic amount of values in an or statement.